# Bring windows application ShowDialog mechanism to android

Tags: android

As you know, we should use `startactivityforresult` and `onactivityresult` to request and return a value between activities in android. But it is hard to manage when you need to get results multiple times in one method (it is easy when you want to start activity at the end of code).

What I mean by 'windows application ShowDialog mechanism' is how to pause (or block) the method when `startactivityforresult` is called, and continue when the result is returned by the second activity.

Comment: "But it is hard to manage when you need to get results multiple times in one method" -- then perhaps the solution is to design a better UI, one that does not involve displaying multiple dialogs in succession.

Comment: @CommonsWare you are right, but I think the whole idea of separating code into two parts (one executing first and the other in onActivityResult) is wrong. You know, this is also a problem in AlertDialogs, if you want to show multiple messages codes will get complicated, but in windows application (.net) they will run in a queue(!)

Comment: the dialog behaviour from winforms is actually really bad and not flexible, but it's possible using a background thread and wait(), notify()